# How to edit Blog HTML to display default search box in mobile theme?

Tags: blogger

I'm trying to include Blogger default search box in mobile display. In the past I managed to do that by simply changing `mobile='no'` to `mobile='yes'` in BlogSearch1, but didn't find that option in *Picture Window* theme. The HTML looks like so:

```
<b:widget id='BlogSearch1' locked='false' title='SEARCH' type='BlogSearch'>
```

Then I included `mobile='yes'`

```
<b:widget id='BlogSearch1' locked='false' mobile='yes' title='SEARCH' type='BlogSearch'>
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use `cond='data:blog.isMobileRequest'`

```xml
<b:widget id='BlogSearch1' type='BlogSearch' cond='data:blog.isMobileRequest'>
```

Comment: I added cond='data:blog.isMobileRequest' but doesn't work. I think that's the code for displaying the search box in desktop theme, but not for mobile theme, like in "Yes. Show mobile theme on mobile devices.".

Comment: That's right, my answer works only on modern themes with one version on desktop and mobile. If you are using the blogger custom mobile version, you can't customize it.

Answer (score 0):

Which theme version you are using? v3 or v2 themes?

For v1 and v2 themes you can use:

**cond="data:view.isMobile"**

For v1 and v2,v3 themes use:

**cond="data:blog.isMobileRequest"**

Comment: It's version 2. The intent is to display the default search box in mobile theme with "Yes. Show mobile theme on mobile devices." It seems it's not possible. Currently I managed to display a search box by changing mobile theme to Dynamic Views.